# How can i read string values from a table , and append to a single string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datatable

I am reading all the string values from a table and adding to an array as follows.

```
da2.Fill(ds, "DNAiusTwitter_Table");
int counts = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
{
    names[i, 0] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
}
```

How can I get string `append = 'name1','name2','name3','name4';` How can I pass those values to this below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    HtmlGenericControl scriptTagLinks = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    scriptTagLinks.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
    string scrip1 = "$(function () {$(\"[src='" + names[i, 0] + "']\"" + ").pinit();});";
    var scrip = "var tweetUsers=['" +append  + "'," + "'" + splitted[3]+"']";
    scriptTagLinks.InnerHtml = scrip;

    this.Controls.Add(scriptTagLinks);
}
```

Comment: Just pass them as parameters of the method hosting the code you are showing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the array later in code, I would use a StringBuilder (System.Text namespace), it has better memory allocation if your table changes in size.

```
da2.Fill(ds, "DNAiusTwitter_Table");
int counts = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
StringBuilder appendString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
{
    appendString.AppendFormat("{0},", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString());
}
```

This will add all the data to the builder, then in the second code snippet, do the following to convert the builder to a string stripping off the additional comma at the end. Also I don't think you need the for loop (loop through 1?) in the second snippet or is the 1 in the for loop a typo?

```
var scrip = "var tweetUsers=['" + appendString.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "'," + "'" + splitted[3]+"']";
```

Answer (score 0):

use string.join() method

Example

```
string.Join(your_array, ",")
```

Comment: I am not able to use joins ,suggest me how to use appends inside the code.